# Partial derivative of $ f(f(x,-x) , f(x,x)) $.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> $ f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R} $ is a function of $C^1$.
>
> and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as :
>
> $$ g(x) = f(f(x,-x) , f(x,x))$$
>
> 1. Compute $g'(x)$.
> 2. Suppose $f(0,0) = 0$. Determine $g'(0)$.
> 3. Prove that if $f(0,0) = 0$ and $(0,0)$ is not a critical point of $f$ then, $g$ is stricly increasing near the point $(0,0)$.

---

I don't know how to answer question $3$, as I am not sure of my answers of question $1$ and $2$. Here is my attempt:

1. Using the chain rule, I got:

$
\begin{align} g'(x) & = \frac{d}{dx} f(f(x,-x) , (x,x))\\
& =   \frac{df}{df}. \frac{df}{dx} (x,-x) + \frac{df}{df}. \frac{df}{dx} (x,x) \\
& = \frac{df}{dx} (x,-x) + \frac{df}{dx} (x,x)
\end{align}$

2. $g'(0) = 2.\frac{df}{dx} (0,0)$

Comment: What's $(x,x)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @lightxbulb It was a mistake, I just corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Whoever wrote this problem is somewhat evil. Using $x$ as the variable for $g$ to allow mixing up $dx$ and $\partial x$. Unnecessary confusion doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Arthur What do you mean? :)

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ are two different things. It's not always something which is looked closely at in introductory multivariable calculus classes, so it's not something everyone pays attention to. For me personally it didn't really click until I encountered Lagrangian mechanics in a general relativity course.

Comment: @Arthur Ah! I thought they are the same. Would you please clarify the difference please? (This was a problem exam) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Basically it would be a lot more readable as $g(t) = f(f(t,-t), f(t,t))$, then $\frac{dg}{dt}(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(f(t,-t), f(t,t))[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,-t) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,-t)] +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(f(t,-t), f(t,t))[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,t) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,t)]$. I think it's an exercise on the chain rule.

Comment: @lightxbulb What are $x$  and $y$ ?

Comment: Components you differentiate with respect to.

Comment: @lightxbulb I am supposed to differentiate with respect to $t$ only. I don't see what I am missing. Would you elaborate more please? Thank you.

Comment: Refer to: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx

Comment: @lightxbulb Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}$ is used for functions which depend on the single variable $x$, and means (total) derivative with respect to that variable. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is used for functions which may depend on several variables, and means the (partial) derivative with respect to whichever of the several variables is called $x$ (usually the first one).

As per my first comment above, I think it's evil (intentional or not) of the problem author to let $g$ depend on $x$. I will therefore change the problem to be about
$$
g(t)=f(f(t,-t), f(t,t))
$$
Using the multivariable chain rule, we get (I hope I didn't mess anything up, this is a lot to keep straight)
$$
\frac{dg}{dt}(t)=\frac{d}{dt}f(t, -t)\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(f(t, -t), f(t, t)) + \frac{d}{dt}f(t, t)\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(f(t, -t), f(t, t))\\
=\left(\frac{dt}{dt}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, -t)+\frac{d(-t)}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t, -t)\right)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(f(t, -t), f(t, t))\\
+\left(\frac{dt}{dt}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, t)+\frac{dt}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t, t)\right)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(f(t, -t), f(t, t))\\
=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, -t)- \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t, -t)\right)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(f(t, -t), f(t, t))
+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t, t)\right)\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(f(t, -t), f(t, t))
$$

Remember that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ specifically means "The partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the first variable", and technically has little to do with the actual variable $x$ (which doesn't even appear here). In the same way, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ means the partial derivative with respect to the second variable.

This is the real meat of the problem. For part 2. inserting $t=0$ and assuming $f(0,0)$ allows a lot of simplification and shouldn't be too problematic. And part $3$ should not be too much trouble either.

Comment: This was an exam problem and yes, that was pure evil. Thank you so much for your help sir. Accepted answer.

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoibi If you encounter something like this in an actual exam, you _are_ allowed to change the name of the variable when doing calculations, and then switch back when you write down the final answer: Now that I have an expression for $g'(t)$, it is rather trivial to get an expression for $g'(x)$.

Comment: I will remember that. Thank you. :)